# How to clear div append results formed during Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Auto Complete for Our Application .

The issue i am facing is that the results that are captured during Auto Complete aren't being cleared up . (The data that is being added to div is  cleardiv)

When i tried to clear it manually on click of  a button ,, the auto complete functionality isn't working .

```
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' />
<div class="autoSearch_result_Wrap" id="Tags_result"></div>
<input type="button" id="cleardiv" value="Clear" name="Clear"><br>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    var aTags = ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: aTags ,
        minLength: 2,
        appendTo: "#Tags_result",
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#cleardiv', function(event) {
    $('#Tags_result').empty();
     });        
});
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/314/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using chrome and the tags clear as soon as i leave the textbox. What browser are you using?

Try this as a test

```
$('#cleardiv').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#tags').blur();        
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/315/